# Any recommendation for IE 6 / 7 Javascript Memory Inspection tool?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory, object

I am looking for an IE 6 / 7 plug-in or something like Firebug_Lite thing that can show the memory usage in runtime, as well as the allocation of memory of each object or variable.  Anyone know what tool has this functionality?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Drip](http://www.outofhanwell.com/ieleak/index.php?title=Main_Page) for memory leaks but in my experience that's pretty much it for IE. Let's wait for better responses :)

Answer (score 0):

Well.  i found out there is a tool called Javascript Memory Validator.  BUt it is expensive and seems like only work for Firefox.  And it is hard to use.
Still looking for a good IE tool for checking the javascript performance & memory allocation.